# Increment sms counter after 160 characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 counters, one to show remaining characters out of 160 per message and another to show total number of sms if characters are more than 160, both working fine untill 160 characters, but after 160 characters, the first counter which shows remaining characters stops to 0, i want that to start again from 160 in decremental way, please check the code and screenshot.

Javascript

```
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit) {
    var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
    if ( field.value.length > maxlimit ) {            
        countfield.value = 160 - field.value.length;              
    } else {
        countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Enter Message" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',160);" ng-model="message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
<br>
Remaining Characters : <input disabled  maxlength="3" size="3" value="160" id="counter"> / SMS
<br>
Total SMS(s) : {{ (message.length - message.length % 160) / 160 + 1 }}
<br>
```

[image]

ADDED

Initially when the text area is empty the Total SMS(s) : NaN, how do i set the initial value for it the expression i have used  there.

Comment: `countfield.value = field.value.length % 160`?

Comment: @Fefux `countfield.value = field.value.length % 160` is incrementing the counter.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry

Comment: @Fefux perfect, sorry it seems it was stupid question.

Comment: @Fefux one more query in the same code, Initially when textarea is empty,  `Total SMS(s) : NaN`, how do i set the initial value to it?

Comment: See my reupdated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to change your js by :

```
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit) {
    var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
    countfield.value = maxlimit - (field.value.length % maxlimit);
}
```

EDIT (With NaN value) :

```
function textCounter(field,field2,maxlimit) {
    var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
    countfield.value = isNaN(field.value.length) ? maxlimit : maxlimit - (field.value.length % maxlimit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get remaining chars for each sms you need

```
 countfield.value = maxlenght - field.value.length % maxlenght ;
```